# How to add extension for Data swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, zip

We are working on zipping image in memory using [GZIP](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP) . It’s working perfectly. The issue is we cannot able to add extension(.jpg for data). How to do that? I will attach my code below.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "test")
let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
do{
//For Zipfile image in memory :
zipdata = try (data!.gzipped(level: .defaultCompression))

}
catch let error{
print(error)
}
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

//For Zipfile:

multipartFormData.append(self.zipdata, withName: "zipfile", fileName: "paperlicense1.zip", mimeType: "application/zip")
```

I want to add the .jpg in the inside the zip file for this data (self.zipdata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gZip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gzip-command-linux/) files have a `.gz` file extension, not `.zip`.

Zip (`.zip`) files are completely different, they use a different algorithim for compression and will structure the file differently.

You either need to send the file as a `.gz` file or use a [Zip library](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip), you don't have to use this particular one, it's just an example. There are quite a few available on GitHub

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's really helpful